# Kubuntu desktop freezes after installing event calendar widget

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I installed the event calendar widget manually via `git clone` and added it to the top bar, and my desktop started to freeze and all of the widgets on the bar and the files on the desktop are not clickable.

- OS: Kubuntu 20.10 x86_64
- DE: Plasma 5.19.5

After restarting, Latte dock doesn't show icons but tooltips show upon hover.

I ran the command `killall plasmashell && plasmashell` and this shows:

```
kf.plasma.quick: Applet preload policy set to 1
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
Loading Calendar plugin HolidaysEventsPlugin(0x560b80a8a140)
file:///home/xm/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.eventcalendar/contents/ui/calendars/PlasmaCalendarManager.qml:16: Error: Qt.createQmlObject(): failed to create object: 
    file:///home/xm/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.eventcalendar/contents/ui/calendars/inline:1:1: module "org.kde.plasma.PimCalendars" is not installed
kf.package: No metadata file in the package, expected it at: "/usr/share/wallpapers/DarkestHour/contents/images/"
kf.package: No metadata file in the package, expected it at: "/usr/share/wallpapers/DarkestHour/contents/images/"
kf.package: No metadata file in the package, expected it at: "/usr/share/wallpapers/DarkestHour/contents/images/"
file:///usr/share/plasma/wallpapers/org.kde.image/contents/ui/main.qml:76:9: Unable to assign [undefined] to QStringList
file:///usr/share/plasma/wallpapers/org.kde.image/contents/ui/main.qml:75:9: Unable to assign [undefined] to int
file:///usr/share/plasma/wallpapers/org.kde.image/contents/ui/main.qml:75:9: Unable to assign [undefined] to int
file:///usr/share/plasma/wallpapers/org.kde.image/contents/ui/main.qml:76:9: Unable to assign [undefined] to QStringList
trying to show an empty dialog
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
3
Plasma Shell startup completed
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:306:17: QML Label: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:306:17: QML Label: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:306:17: QML Label: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:306:17: QML Label: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:306:17: QML Label: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:306:17: QML Label: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:306:17: QML Label: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:306:17: QML Label: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:306:17: QML Label: Binding loop detected for property "width"
Entry is not valid "kontact.desktop" QSharedPointer(0x560b834bf1e0)
Entry is not valid "ktp-contactlist.desktop" QSharedPointer(0x560b834bf1e0)
Entry is not valid "kontact.desktop" QSharedPointer(0x560b8346c0e0)
Entry is not valid "ktp-contactlist.desktop" QSharedPointer(0x560b8346c0e0)
file:///home/xm/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.eventcalendar/contents/ui/calendars/PlasmaCalendarManager.qml:16: Error: Qt.createQmlObject(): failed to create object: 
    file:///home/xm/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.eventcalendar/contents/ui/calendars/inline:1:1: module "org.kde.plasma.PimCalendars" is not installed
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.panelspacer/contents/ui/main.qml:53:5: Unable to assign [undefined] to QQuickGridLayout*
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.panelspacer/contents/ui/main.qml:53:5: Unable to assign [undefined] to QQuickGridLayout*
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.milou/contents/ui/main.qml:61:17: Unable to assign double to QQuickAnchorLine
trying to show an empty dialog
Qt Quick Layouts: Detected recursive rearrange. Aborting after two iterations.
trying to show an empty dialog
trying to show an empty dialog
libkcups: CUPS-Get-Printers last error: 0 successful-ok
libkcups: Create-Printer-Subscriptions last error: 0 successful-ok
libkcups: Get-Jobs last error: 0 successful-ok
libkcups: Get-Jobs last error: 0 successful-ok
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.battery/contents/ui/CompactRepresentation.qml:54:17: Unable to assign [undefined] to int
libkcups: 5 "XXXXXX"
libkcups: 3 "XXXXX_Series@xxxxx.local"
libkcups: 3 "XXXXXX"
libkcups: 0
libkcups: 0
trying to show an empty dialog
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
trying to show an empty dialog
Qt Quick Layouts: Detected recursive rearrange. Aborting after two iterations.
Qt Quick Layouts: Detected recursive rearrange. Aborting after two iterations.
Qt Quick Layouts: Detected recursive rearrange. Aborting after two iterations.
trying to show an empty dialog
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.milou/contents/ui/main.qml:61:17: Unable to assign double to QQuickAnchorLine
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.milou/contents/ui/main.qml:61:17: Unable to assign double to QQuickAnchorLine
trying to show an empty dialog
```

Comment: There might be some compatibility issues.  Saw a similar thread on Arch Linux where they had to remove it. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=259007

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem a few days ago, and the only solution that i could find, was to delete the event calendar widget. Its a very easy and simple task:

1. First, you need to delete manually this folder: `///home/xm/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.eventcalendar`
2. And then you can start plasmashell again, and can uninstall the widget, and it will clean everything else from event calendar.

Sadly i don't know when they will fix this bug, but till then i recommend using KOrganizer! ;)