# Plasma desktop crashing in 21.04

Tags: kubuntu, 21.04

21.04 is finally rolling out as an upgrade. However, after upgrading, the plasma desktop crashes soon after login.

Keyboard shortcuts work, I can start a Terminal or Dolphin, but no taskbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the problem was due to the Event Calendar widget.

Referring to the answer at [Kubuntu desktop freezes after installing event calendar widget](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310582/kubuntu-desktop-freezes-after-installing-event-calendar-widget#) I opened a Terminal via keyboard shortcut, and entered the following

```
cd ~/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids
mv "org.kde.plasma.eventcalendar" "org.kde.plasma.eventcalendar.old"
```

I then entered `plasmashell` to test it, and it works.

People upgrading Kubuntu are advised to disable Event Calendar beforehand.